What is the Dialogflow CX Parameter String Length Limit
I am unable to find any answers on Google's documentation. The closest I've been able to find is here:
https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/quotas#length_limits
The documentation states that Maximum text response length is 4000 characters, but after testing a parameter value with over 4000 characters, it appears this doesn't seem to be the same.
Is anyone able to confirm what the size limit is for parameter values?
